# OpenCV: multiply Mat with Scalar in Kotlin on Android

Tags: android, opencv, camera, kotlin

I'm writing an Android App, using the Camera API 2. It takes 3 pictures in burst mode with different exposure values and merges them with OpenCV (3.0.0). By merging I mean the Mertens algorithm, which is available in the Photo module. In order to save the result as a image on the device, I need to multiply it with a scalar. If I don't do it, then the resulting image is black.

```
    fun multiply(src: Mat): Mat {
        val scalar = Scalar(255.0,255.0,255.0)
        val dest = Mat()
        Core.multiply(src, scalar, dest)
        return dest
    }
```

The source image (src) is of 320x240 CV_32FC3.

But the multiplying fails:

```
android-pack/opencv/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:1987: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function void cv::arithm_op(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, cv::InputArray, int, void (**)(const uchar*, size_t, const uchar*, size_t, uchar*, size_t, cv::Size, void*), bool, void*, int)
```

It is strange that this piece of code, written in Java with the old Camera API, works. But I don't think that this is the cause.

So what am I doing wrong here? How can I dive deeper to find the cause?

Answer (score 0):

After spending several days on this problem I found a workaround. Unfortunetly I can't really say why the above posted version didn't work.

Even after creating a destination image of the same size and type, the core refused to multiply.

```
val dest = Mat(src.size(), src.type())
Core.multiply.(src, scalar, dest) //still raised exception
```

I studied more of the [javadoc](https://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/core/Core.html#multiply(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Scalar,%20org.opencv.core.Mat)) of the core module. One sentence gave me a hint to try it in a another way:

> There is also a "MatrixExpressions" -friendly variant of the first function. See "Mat.mul".

So I changed my multiply method:

```
fun multiply(src: Mat): Mat {
  val scalar = Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0)
  val filter = Mat(src.size(), src.type(), scalar)
  return src.mul(filter)
}
```

And it worked! This snippet looks even more elegant because it returns the value immedialtely, instead of modyfying a local variable

Answer (score 0):

That means `src` and `dest` have difference sizes.

You need to create `dest` with:

```
val dest = Mat(src.width, src.height)
```